# Stop auto-powering-on my USB drive after I power it off

Tags: usb, mount, usb-drive

My USB 3.0 drives turn on after I turn them off in the Disks utility.

I've [disabled auto-mounting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) via org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.automount. This worked as expected but doesn't help with my power on/off problem.

This only seems to happen when I use `dd` to write a disk image. Here's my workflow:

1. Insert a USB drive from step 6
2. Write USB drive using `sudo dd if=someFile of=/dev/sdb bs=8M oflag=sync && sync`
3. Power down USB drive in "Disks" GUI. The drive disappears from the Devices list
4. Wait a second. The drive reappears in the Devices list.
5. Repeat (3). The drive continues to reappear.
6. Remove drive from PC anyway.

I'd like to cut out steps 4 and 5. Why is the device being re-enabled?

I'm using 14.04.

Comment: hey OP, I didn't notice your post before, but I'm having the [exact same issue](http://askubuntu.com/q/630078/301745)

Comment: try to turn off with **hdparam**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try some other dd/usb-port/usb-cable ?

I had the same problem with my old DD. It was not getting enough power from my usb cable. It connected without problem and disconnected when I tried to use it. Maybe you have the same problem.

Comment: OP's issue is that the drive **re**connects, not that it disconnects.